# Scrollbar style on datatable

Tags: jquery, css, .net, model-view-controller, datatable

How can i style a specific datatable scorllbar with webkit. Here is the code:

```
    id ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    id::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 13px;
    }
    id::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:40%;
    background-color: #999999;
```

but this style change my scrollbar of entire datatables from whole project. I've tried with a class but still dosen't work.

**Please help**

Answer (score 5):

DataTables use **dataTables_scrollBody** class at tbody, so you can style like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.dataTables_scrollBody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.dataTables_scrollBody::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.dataTables_scrollBody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 9px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(192,192,192,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to style only one scrollbar in a specific datatable, not all. I don't know why the scrollbar doesn't take my table id or class

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar is a pseudo element of another element. Hence, you can style it by targeting whichever element's overflow causes it to appear.

Here's an example of two elements with two different scrollbars:

```css
.scrollbar-1,
.scrollbar-2 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Element specific scrollbar styling */

.scrollbar-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: gray;
}
 
.scrollbar-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
}

.scrollbar-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: yellow;
}
 
.scrollbar-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue; 
}

/* Common styling for all scrollbars */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbar-1">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc a risus arcu. Ut tempor laoreet turpis. Curabitur facilisis faucibus massa sit amet imperdiet. Fusce vestibulum sodales egestas. Donec mattis fringilla ante non euismod. Donec ullamcorper odio at ligula maximus ullamcorper.
</div>

<div class="scrollbar-2">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc a risus arcu. Ut tempor laoreet turpis. Curabitur facilisis faucibus massa sit amet imperdiet. Fusce vestibulum sodales egestas. Donec mattis fringilla ante non euismod. Donec ullamcorper odio at ligula maximus ullamcorper.
</div>
```

However, you can't add a scrollbar to a table element. A solution to that might be wrapping the table in a div and applying the scrollbar styling to said div, or applying the styling to the tbody element.

HTML:

```
<div class="scrollbar">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
```

or HTML:

```
<table class="table-scrollbar">
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-scrollbar tbody::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it's still not working...i don't know what is the problem with DataTable...i've tried with E[foo^="bar"]  type of selector but still doesn't work...i'm ruined

Comment: Here's a guess, given that you haven't posted any code apart from the actual scrollbars: Besides the scrollbar styling you'll need to make sure the element has a `height` specified, as well as `overflow` set to auto or scroll. Could that be it?

Comment: I had specified in my stylesheet  this :#tableId {
    z-index: 20;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size:11px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

Comment: and in the <script> for jquery Datatable this : var table = $('#tableId').DataTable({
            searchHighlight: true,
            autoWidth: false,
           //important column width do not remove
            columns: [               
                { width : '10%' },
                { width: '90%' },],
            scrollY: '600px',
            scrollX: false,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
.I don't know why doesn't take my selector or somthing like this. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Well, `overflow: hidden;` actually _hides_ the scrollbar. The values you're looking for in stead of hidden would be `auto` or `scroll`. Also, remember to specify a height, as the contents won't overflow otherwise. And as mentioned, you'll need to apply this styling to a container div or the tbody element, not to the table element.

Comment: Thanks for the adivice!